# Minimize coding for validation in C#

Tags: c#, .net, validation, design-patterns, reusability

I'm trying to validate a set of Textboxes in a winform application.

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCarbohydrate.Text){

            //todo
        }
```

but there are several Textboxes in my form to be validated for emptiness , not only in the current win form but other forms too. how can i create  a method or a class that can validate several Textboxes and 
be reusable across application?

EDIT : i wrote somthing like this , any suggestion to make it better ?

```
  class ValidateEmpty
  {
    bool res = false;
    //List<object> txt = new List<object>();
    List<string> st = new List<string>();

    public List<string> St
    {
        get { return st; }
        set { st = value; }
    }

    public ValidateEmpty(List<string> _str)
    {
        this.st = _str;
    }      

    public bool checkEmpty()
    {
        bool res = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < St.Count(); i++ )
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(St[i]))
            {
                res= true;                   
            }
        }
            return res;
    }
}
```

}
`

Comment: Use attribute required. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.aspx

Comment: Note that you can `return true;` in the middle of your `CheckEmpty()` loop; no need to keep checking once you've established that at least one box is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put them in a list and then loop through the list.

```
List<TextBox> TextBoxes=new List<TextBox>() {txtCarbohydrate, txtProtein, txtFat};

foreach(TextBox tb in TextBoxes)
{
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Based on your edit, you want to return a Boolean (it's really hard to understand your code and what you're trying to accomplish, you need to be clear and concise!) to indicate if a TextBox was empty or not.  Here's how you could create a method to do that...

```
public static bool IsThereAnEmptyTextBox(List<TextBox> textBoxes)
{
    bool emptyfound=false;
    foreach(TextBox tb in textboxes)
    {
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text)
        {
            emptyfound=true;
        }   
    }
    return emptyfound;
}
```

You can call this function from any class, if you put this function in a Utility class or in a base class etc. If you want to combine it with paqogomez's answer you can call it from a form like this...

```
bool emptyfound=MyUtilities.IsThereAnEmptyTextBox(myForm.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList());
```

I think this is a terrible way of going about it, but I'm trying to demonstrate how you could do what you've asked for.

Comment: thanks , but what if i want to resuse thos peice of code in other forms ?

Comment: It's hard to say without looking at how you want to reuse it.

Comment: i want a method that accept any number of Textboxes and check them for emptiness. and i want to be able to use it any where in my app without coding each time.

Comment: While you could easily write a function to accept a List of TextBoxes and loop through them, what isn't so easy is performing the action. The "do something" part in the code I wanted. Usually that message will be specific to the TextBox and the Form. Kind of hard to centralize that.

Comment: why it's terrible ? it prevents repetitive coding. suggest the best way then , tnx

Comment: You're simply returning a boolean to indicate if they're empty or not. Instead, you should check each one and let the user know which ones are empty but required. You need to follow good UI paradigms. Using the RequiredAttribute that Rand Random mentioned in his comment on your question would be a good start to that.

Answer (score 3):

To grab all textboxes in a single form use [`Controls.OfType<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var controls = myForm.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();

foreach(TextBox tb in controls)
{
  //do validation
}
```

Depending on the type of validation you are doing, you can also do as @RandRandom suggests and put the required attribute on your textboxes.  This will force the user to put text in before its submitted.

Comment: thanks , but if i want to reuse this, should i put it in calss ?

Comment: @Iatrochemist Putting it in a class wouldnt really make sense.  Perhaps a base class however.  A base class could have a "ValidateTextBoxes" method in it.  Then all of your forms that required this could inherit from it.

Comment: is it the class that u talking about ? pls see the edit.

Comment: wouldn't `OfType` be better? `Cast` will throw `InvalidCastException` if a control cannot be casted

Comment: @Default thanks , but what do u mean by ofType ?pls explain .\

Comment: @Iatrochemist, see my edit for the explaination of `OfType`.  it is a better solution, thanks default.

Comment: @Iatrochemist make it a base class.  `public class ValidateEmpty: Form`, then on your form `public class MyForm: ValidateEmpty`